# ServiceStack xml nil

Tags: xml, null, servicestack

Starting to play with ServiceStack and I'm looking for a way to exclude null properties on the Response DTO when exporting as xml.
This is the sort of thing I want to omit...

```
<SectorCode i:nil="true"/>
```

I know how to do this with ordinary Xml serialization but I'm struggling to find an option/attribute that will do this in ServiceStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't have it's own XML Serializer, it just uses .NET's default DataContract Serializer so you'll need to use .NET's DataContract/DataMember attributes to customize how it's serialized, e.g:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = false)]
    public string SectorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Note when you annotate your class with `[DataContract]` it becomes opt-in and you'll need to annotate each public property you want serialized with `[DataMember]`.